# matlab R2020a Problem creating and writing to file when running in background on Linux

Tags: matlab

I am working on linux with matlabR2020a. My program test.m is below:

```
%test.m
fid=fopen(strcat('test','.txt'),'w');
fprintf(fid, '%.4f %.4f\n', 0.1, 0.2);
fclose(fid);
exit;
```

When I run the program like this it works fine:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "test"
```

However, when I try to run in the background, it fails to create the file:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "test" &
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any error messages? Does MATLAB exit? You should use the new `-batch` option instead of `-r`.

Comment: switching to -batch fixed it. thanks!